# How to add existing element attribute to child element while append that child element?

Tags: jquery

here the HTML
span to be appended to this div

```
<div class="new">
    <a value="03" id="a1"></a>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

ul contains element to show

```
<ul id="ad1" class="drpdwn">
    <li value="1">
        <input type="checkbox" value="2" id="ck1" name="Drop Shadows"/>
        <span id="sp1"> Drop Shadows</span>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="2" id="ck2" name="Reflections">
        <span id="sp2">Reflections</span>
    </li>
    <li><a id="ck3" name="General Spotting" alt="1"/>General Spotting</a></li>
    <li><a id="ck4" name="Gene Spotting" alt="1"/> Spotting</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here The jQuery Code

```
$('#ck2').click(function () {
    option = $('#sp2').text();
```

here id ck2 th attrbute are set to var ot

```
ot=$('#ck2').attr("value");
    alert(ot);
```

here i set id ck2'th attr to appended span.help me out.!

```
  $('.new span').append('<span id="span1"></span>').attr(ot);

  $('#span1').html(option);
  oc=$('#span1').attr("name" ,"value");
  alert(oc);
  })
```

Comment: I assume the missing `</li>` tag (to close your *first* `li` element) is a typo when copying your code? If not, please edit your question and correct the code to accurately represent what you've got.

Comment: `here i set id ck2'th attr to appended span..` Which attribute..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure what you are asking for... but assuming thisi swhat you want

```
$('.new span').append('<span id="span1" value="'+ot +'"></span>');
```

this will append span with attributes id as span1 and value as 2.. like wise you can do for name ..